# Почему не работает регулярка на php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Регулярка на php должна находить слово "культурист" либо в начале строки, либо в конце либо, если оно в середине окружено круглыми скобками например: тест1 (культурист) тест2.

Подскажите, плиз, почему не работают обратные ссылки:

```
$str ="культурист тест1 (культурист) тест2";
$res = preg_match("/(культурист)$|^\\1|\(\\1\)/iu", $str, $match, 
PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($match);
```

Не находит ничего (найдет только, если слово поставить в конце строки).

Comment: нет соответствия шаблону - нет и обратной ссылки

Comment: не понял, можете пояснить вашу мысль?
шаблон для 1 группы символов: (культурист)

Comment: шаблон у вас `(культурист)$`, а `(культурист)` это группа захвата. Если шаблон в целом не выполняется, то и группы не будет никакой

Comment: напишите без обратных ссылок да и все дела

Comment: Без обратных ссылок-то я написал, но хочется упростить, т.к. на самом деле задание более сложное (я для простоты написал культурист, но по факту групппа захвата такая (программ?ист[а-яА-Я]*), т.е мм или м + в любом падеже + единст./множеств. число. Сами понимаете повторять такое три раза как-то не комильфо.

Answer (score 4):

## Небольшое упрощение

Для большей ясности сначала переведу Ваше регулярное выражение в одинарные кавычки:

```
'/(культурист)$|^\1|\(\1\)/iu'
```

Все дальнейшие регулярки тоже буду приводить в одинарных кавычках.

## Устранение проблемы

Сперва дам простой способ устранения проблемы. Для ваших целей следует использовать такую регулярку:

```
'/(культурист)$|^(?1)|\((?1)\)/iu'
```

– то есть вместо [обратных ссылок](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.back-references.php) `\1` следует использовать [рекурсивные подмаски](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php) `(?1)`. Разница в следующем:

- обратные ссылки сопоставляются с конкретными текстовыми строками, которые были захвачены из текста подмаской
- рекурсивные подмаски работают как "подпрограммы" – они подставляют указанную подмаску "как есть" на место вызова, независимо от того, какая строка была захвачена ей ранее (см.эквивалентную регулярку ниже)

Потестировать вживую предложенное решение можно здесь: https://regex101.com/r/3hOm5A/1 – заодно я добавил там тестовый пример со всеми кейсами.

## Теперь главное: почему так происходит?

В своей регулярке Вы используете обратные ссылки совместно с альтернативным выбором. Как только первая альтернатива `(культурист)$` отрабатывает, начинается вторая альтернатива `^\1`. При переходе от альтернативы к альтернативе все обратные ссылки как бы "обнуляются". То есть считается, что в пределах данной (второй) альтернативы ещё никакой текст для первой подмаски не был найден. Подмаска есть, но обратная ссылка уже не хранит текст, который был ей сопоставлен в предыдущей альтернативе. То же самое происходит при переходе к третьей альтернативе. Именно поэтому две последних альтернативы у Вас не работают. Они просто не имеют доступа к ранее найденному тексту.

В свою очередь моё решение использует не обратные ссылки, а рекурсивные подмаски. В данном случае первая подмаска подставляется в альтернативные ветки как есть. В результате моя регулярка становится эквивалентна следующей:

```
'/(культурист)$|^культурист|\(культурист\)/iu'
```

– именно поэтому она отлично работает.

Comment: Шикарное объяснение! Респектище вам!